# Timer task makes app crash

Tags: java, android

I have a Canvas object in my app and I want to update it each 20 ms. I tried Java's TimerTask, but it makes my app crash after few updates. Here's update code;

```
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate(); // canvas's update
        }
    }, 20, 20);
```

What shall I do?

Edit: Error log:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: You shall show us the error messages in your Logcat.

Comment: post your logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `run()` is called on a background thread, and `invalidate()` is called on that background thread. This will lead to the exception you have in your question, as those sorts of updates can only be done on the main application thread.

Since calling `invalidate()` 50 times/second is unlikely to be the right solution for whatever problem you are trying to solve, you may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain what sorts of changes you are trying to make to your UI every 20ms, to see what the recommended approach is. Or, pick up a book on Android game development — while you may not be building a game, game developers drawing to a `Canvas` also have these sorts of concerns, so the techniques that they use might be relevant to you as well.

Comment: This is a really small game project i have finish from given code. It uses canvas and I musn't change it.

Comment: @MicrovaveProgrammer: That does not mean that calling `invalidate()` 50 times a second is the right solution for whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you really *want* to do this, just change `invalidate` to `postInvalidate`.